# Angular: Get last 3 elements of json object

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page that list an item and let users add comments to it.

1. On that page I would like to display the last 3 comments added. Any tips on how to do get the last 3 comments from JSON objects?
2. Also when adding a new comment how can I increment the comment number (hardcoded for now)?

See my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/iOBXuQVY40LD8d8QV5ss?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: My answer displays the last three comments, updates the comment count (including each added comment description).   Is that what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: @lucuma any chance you could take a look at my EDIT?

Comment: I forked it and made some changes:  http://plnkr.co/edit/6LKdy43jw6o4J507YfKc?p=preview  I think what you had could be simplified.  Check it out.

Comment: Instead of asking more question please award the answer to one of the posts below. I believe they all answer your original question

Comment: You've already awarded an answer so presumably you are asking a new question so can you post your edits as a new specific question.

Comment: @lucuma No worries, I created a new question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448973/angular-communication-between-controllers-and-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on other answers: You should look at adding an ID or date to each comment. For my example solution, I've used "`ID`".

In my forked plunk, I've added a total, and a 'show more' button for an expandable comment list. The size is controlled by the variable '`limit`'.

Also, the variable '`itemID`' inside `$scope.addMessage()` is adding the `ID` to each comment. This will solve part 2 of your question.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/bAtXmCls2gk8p5WAHsrM?p=preview

**$scope.addMessage (adds item, description has the value of whatever you put in the input box and resets limit back to latest 3)**

```
  $scope.addMessage = function(mess) {
    var itemID = $scope.items[0].comments.length + 1;
    $scope.items[0].comments.push(
          {
            "id": itemID,
            "name":"user" + itemID,
            "description": mess
          }
      );
    $scope.totalItems = itemID;
    $scope.limit = 3;
  }
```

**$scope.showMore (increases limit by 3)**

```
  $scope.showMore = function() {
    $scope.limit += 3;
  }
```

**JSON: I've changed it a little. 'comments' is now an array, and an 'id' is added**

```
    "comments":
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"user1",
        "description": "This is comment 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name":"Jane D.",
        "description": "This is comment 2"
      },
      ...
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys! Comments "id" should have been added to my original code.. my bad. @rudeovski-ze-bear Your version seems close to what I was looking for. I'll test it and come back to you asap. Thanks again.

Comment: @Patrice no problem. Remember, if this did solve your issue, please mark it as answered.

Comment: A few more questions if that's okay? See my **EDIT** and plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/w4Tpz0Tp53fXRZj7Jbbe?p=preview Added some comments to the code.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [limitTo Filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3alimitTo). You can specific from the end of a list by using negative.

You could do

```
message in item.comments|limitTo:-3
```

Also for your comments, you should haven't them as a object dictionary, rather just use an array like so:

```
"comments":
        [
          {
            "id": "comment1",
            "name":"user1",
            "description": "This is comment 1"
          },
          {
            "id": "comment2",
            "name":"Jane D.",
            "description": "This is comment 2"
          },
          {
            "id": "comment3",
            "name":"Jone D.",
            "description": "This is comment 3"
          },
          {
            "id": "comment4",
            "name":"Test",
            "description": "This is comment 4"
          },
          {
            "id": "comment5",
            "name":"user",
            "description": "This is comment 5"
          }
        ]
```

If they aren't already in order you may need to add a date field of sort and sort them after you pull them in.

Here is a [update plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j5ui7Awh1LRLdZt0Da5o?p=preview) to help you out. Note your ng-repeat was also in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to note:

I changed the comments to be an array in the json.  For some reason you had it as an object.

You can use the `limitTo` filter to limit to the last three.  `<li ng-repeat="message in item.comments | limitTo:-3"></li>`

My answer includes the total and functioning add comment.

Controller code :

```
myApp.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Items){

  Items.get(function(response){
    $scope.items = response; 

  })

  $scope.$watch('items', function() {
     $scope.total = $scope.items[0].comments.length;
  });

  $scope.addMessage = function(mess) {
    $scope.items[0].comments.push(
      {
        "name":"user1",
        "description": "This is comment " + ($scope.total + 1) 
      }
    );
  }

})
```

Updated Plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/2oWLRU06Kdp0yKqjodmv?p=preview

Comment: 2 more questions on the same topic if that's Okay? See my EDIT. Expanding from your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/W5FibkcRzjKeM5iO2gtn?p=preview